# How to create a program that uses an array to count vowels?

Tags: java, arrays

I am having some trouble creating a program that uses an array to count vowels in names entered by a user. The user should be able to enter up to 1000 names or say "Done" to end the program. Once the user gets to 1000 names or says done, it is supposed to display the total amount of vowels in each name combined.
Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Countvowels
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int LOW ='A';
        final int HIGH = 'Z';
        int[] letterCounts = new int[HIGH-LOW+1];
        String[] word = new String[1000];
        char[] wordLetter;
        int offset;
        System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
        for(int letter = 0; letter < wordLetter.length; letter++){
            word[letter] = input.nextLine();
            wordLetter = word.toCharArray();

        }
    }
}
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: What problems you have in the current program?

Comment: I know I need to use an if statement to obtain the amount of vowels in a name, but I do not know how to make the array equal the unicode for A E I O U.

Comment: Why would you use an array or list to hold the counts? A `Map<Character, Integer>` seems much, much simpler and more appropriate.

Comment: I agree, but this is an assignment in which we must use arrays.

Comment: I don't believe the way you've asked the question is appropriate, then. As it's currently worded, you've essentially asked us to write your code for you (which a number of answers have done). This will not help you learn the material as well as struggling through it yourself. If you have a more specific question, we might be able to do more to help you understand the concepts, but it's too broad for that in its current form.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind all that code. You only need one line:

```
String[] word = new String[1000]; // given this

int vowels = Arrays.toString(word).replaceAll("(?i)[^aeiou]", "").length();
```

This first converts the array to a string (basically a csv), then replaces all non-vowels (fyi `(?i)` is the case-insensitive flag) with nothing (ie deleting them), then with only vowels left just take the length.

Comment: +1 for good answer, but I think helping OP to find his actual error will make him better understand his problems.

Comment: Now thats a simple answer while still being advanced  ;)

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun but I like to crush feeble newbie with my regex kung fu... muhahahaha

Comment: not that OP is likely to ever thank anyone for anything but a fully working solution OP can hand in to his teacher as his own creation.

Comment: I'm seriously debating whether to -1 this based on doing the OP's homework for them. =)

Comment: @jpmc26 there is no way he could hand this code in and pass it off as his. There aren't too many professional java programmers that could come up with this, and no beginners. I posted it more as an example what *can* be done with the language when you know it well, and for entertainment. To be frank, it's probably closer to a flag for "doesn't answer the question" than a downvote, but it does answer OP's program's *intention* if not the problem with his chosen approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a total for all vowels @Bohemian has an excellent answer.  If you need them seperate it might be easier to do the following:

Just create 1 big string with all the user input.

Then for example when you end up with:

```
String userInput = 'JohnMaryLisaPeter';


for(int x = 0; x <= userInput.length() - 1; x++) {
    if(userInput.charAt(x) == 97)
        vowelA++;
    else if(userInput.charAt(x) == 101)
        vowelE++;
    else if(userInput.charAt(x) == 105)
        vowelI++;
    else if(userInput.charAt(x) == 111)
        vowelO++;
    else if(userInput.charAt(x) == 117)
        vowelU++;   
} 

System.out.println("There were " + vowelA + " A's in all your names.");
System.out.println("There were " + vowelE + " E's in all your names.");
System.out.println("There were " + vowelI + " I's in all your names.");
System.out.println("There were " + vowelO + " O's in all your names.");
System.out.println("There were " + vowelU + " U's in all your names.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Three errors I see:

You have the array-of-characters

```
char[] wordLetter;
```

in which the vowels *will* go, yet you're using it as the for-loop termination. There's nothing in the array yet--there is no array at all, just a marker in memory where it *will* be created--so you are comparing letter against nothingness!

```
for(int letter = 0; letter < wordLetter.length; letter++){
```

It should be

```
for(int letter = 0; letter < [some_number_here]; letter++){
```

In the for-loop, you are attempting to change the entire *array* of words to a character array, which makes no sense. Naming the array of words `word` is confusing you. Try `aWords` or something.

```
          wordLetter = word.toCharArray();
```

Fix:

```
          wordLetter = word[letter].toCharArray();
```

And `letter` is another bad choice of variable names. Try `iIndex`.

I hope this helps!